# what is the flow of control in following program?

Tags: c, pipe, fork

I am  learning to use fork and pipes. I wrote the following code.The child1 writes "child 1 " and child2 writes "child 2", and the parent reads the values.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>

int main()
{
int pfds[2];
char buf[30];
pipe(pfds);
if(fork() == 0)     //child 1
{
    close(pfds[0]);
    write(pfds[1],"child 1",sizeof(buf));
}
else
{   
    if(fork() == 0)  //child2
    { close(pfds[0]);
      write(pfds[1],"child 2",sizeof(buf));

    }
    else
    {
      close(pfds[1]);
      read(pfds[0],buf,sizeof(buf));
      printf(" read: %s ",buf);
      wait(NULL);

    }

close(pfds[1]);
read(pfds[0],buf,sizeof(buf));
printf(" read: %s ",buf);       
wait(NULL); 
}


}
```

My output is: read: some_garbage_value  read: child 1  read: child 2 

 Why am I getting read 3 times? I want it only for 2 times( child1 and child2). How are the statements getting executed? 

P.S: sorry if this is a noob question. I have just started learning fork(), exec() and pipes.

Comment: Include newlines in your outputs.

Comment: The children `close(pfds[0])`, then later `read(pfds[0])`. That's insane. As is `close()`ing `pfds[1]` twice in the parent.

Comment: You are not checking the return value of read.

Comment: The parent prints two "read" statements, child 2 prints one (which is junk).

Comment: @stark: nor the return value of `pipe()`, nor the return value of `fork()` for failure, nor that of `close()`...

Comment: You have a lot of problems to deal with.  You're writing more data than there is in the strings you're using, so you're writing garbage.  You're not paying attention to how much data was available for reading.  And the flow of control is tricky because children are not exiting, so they resume at later stages in the operation.  Use `fprintf(stderr, …)` copiously, and print the PID in front of each message (and end each message with a newline). Check errors and return values from `read()`.

Comment: ^I will surely keep a check on the return values from next time. this is hardly the 2nd or 3rd program I wrote using fork and pipes. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Neglecting the plethora of errors and missing checks in your code (already pointed out in comments), the problem you are asking for is given by the fact that `fork()` splits the flow into two paths which are executed on two different processes. This means that after the `fork()` you will have two executions in parallel in which in one `fork()` returned 0 and in the other returned the pid of the created process.

So after first `fork()` you will have a process executing the `if` branch and a process executing the `else` branch.

Then you fork again in a piece of code done in this way:

```
if (fork() == 0) {
  code1;
}
else {
  code2;
}

code3;
```

Now imagine two different processes in which fork() returned a different value, you'd have:

```
if (0 == 0)
  code1;
else
  code2;

code3;
```

and

```
if (123 == 0)
  code1;
else
  code2;

code3;
```

Which means that the two paths are resolved as:

```
code1;
code3;
```

and

```
code2;
code3;
```

Which explains why the second child you create attempts a read.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what happens:

First fork:

- first child : just writes and exits
- parent forks one second time

  - child closes `pfds[0]`, writes... and proceed after the else to read from `pfds[0]` that has just been closed. As you do not test return value of `read` the second childs prints a random buffer to stdout
  - parent reads a buffer from `pfds[0]` and prints it to stdout, then proceeds after the if to read a second buffer and prints it also to stdout

So we have one garbage output and two correct ones. Compiler is right.

You can easily fix it by immediately returning from child 2:

```
if(fork() == 0)  //child2
{ close(pfds[0]);
  write(pfds[1],"child 2",sizeof(buf));
  return 0;   /* stop child2 immediately */
}
else
```

Comment: Adding return makes the program give the output I wanted.

Comment: So this is what I understood - the second fork's child writes in the buffer and also tries executing the default statements( 3rd last line of else part of first if) in the else part of first if. and the return is some incorrect value which gets printed. Is my interpretation correct?